# Bullet spawning at world origin instead of muzzle socket on static mesh

Tags: transformation, mesh, unreal-5, spawning

I placed a socket called "Muzzle" on the end of my static mesh as shown here

[image: Muzzle at the end of a barrel]

I have it so when I left click, my bullet should spawn on the muzzle socket, but for whatever reason, it spawns at the world origin instead.

This text shows where the bullet spawns when the mesh that supposedly contains the socket moves around. As you see, the bullets spawn in the same location, meaning the socket must not be moving, right?

```
Translation: X=0.000 Y=0.000 Z=0.000 Rotation: P=0.000 Y=0.000 R=0.000 Scale X=0.362 Y=0.362 Z=0.362
Translation: X=0.000 Y=0.000 Z=0.000 Rotation: P=0.000 Y=0.000 R=0.000 Scale X=0.362 Y=0.362 Z=0.362
Translation: X=0.000 Y=0.000 Z=0.000 Rotation: P=0.000 Y=0.000 R=0.000 Scale X=0.362 Y=0.362 Z=0.362
```

This is the part of the blueprint for the gun that I think might be the issue. The `StartFire` event triggers when I left click.

[image: Blueprint]

and finally [this is the tutorial I'm following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hI8mMRI8dRM).